# Window.open() how to determine the default value of width/height when not set

Tags: window.open

I want to know the default value of `width/height` when not passing value to function

Answer (score 0):

Read the document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

"If the windowFeatures parameter is non-empty and no size features are defined, then the new window dimensions will be the same as the dimensions of the most recently rendered window."

Comment: when opening IE full screen, popup open doesn't follow the size of the most recently rendered window